# Altium 15 BGA Fanout option is not working fully

Tags: altium, routing, bga

I'm trying to fanout and route a 0.5mm pitch BGA component by creating a ROOM and setting a sepcific BGA rules for that particular component.

I followed this video below 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUSi4rxBhsY

The compoenet I'm working on is this
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/afe4403.pdf

The rules I used are as follows and considered from TI recommendations link below:
Clearance : 3.2mil
Width: 4mil and/or 8mil
Via: 10/5mil

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprabb3/sprabb3.pdf (see page 11,12 for 0.5mm pitch BGA)

I tried exactly as shown in the above video and also tried changing couple of options in FANOUT prompt. But what ever I try the output is only applying to specific pads in outer rows and not all the nets are pads are fanned out.

Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I found the fix. Actually from the video the OP only changes one sub-rule named Fanout_BGA (red circle in the above pic) under Fanout Control rules.

But the next important sub rule named Fanout_Default needs to be checked and make sure the Fanout Style is set to BGA. There are 4 types of Fanouts and each Fanout has their own set of rules to be defined and finally only one can be used as default and which is where we've to set the Fanout_Default to any one of the styles before applying.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not help, I still cannot make fanouts.
What else could be the problem?

Comment: @Veronika There could be various things affecting the fanout, most important thing is to create separate set of rules prior to fan out. To address the issue it would be helpful if you could share more details like what size of BGA component and Altium errors(if any) that you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes too late to help the OP, however it may be of value to future readers.  If there are any polygons on signal layers that are in the stackup under the part you are trying to fan out, try shelving them.  That has stopped me from being able to fan out in the past.